# Puppeteer page's content when I pass it to another function vanishes

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

I'm using Puppeteer to web scrap my website. I'm using `await page.content()` and console logging it and I'm getting the content in the logs but when I pass `page` as an argument to another javascript function. The `await page.content()` is null. Nothing is present in the content even though I can still see the content in the browser. I have no idea why this is happening, I did literally the same things for other url of the same website but they are working fine. Only in this case, the `await page.content()` is returning null. I know that I can pass `await page.content()` as an argument directly but that won't suffice because I have conditions when to call this, otherwise server load would be high.

```
func1(){
   let a = await page.content()
   console.log(a) // works fine and prints the html
}

func2(){
 func3(page);
}

func3(page){
 let c = await page.content()
 console.log(c);
 //Prints nothing
}
```

Comment: Can you show the full script, where you call the function in which `page.content()` gets called? Probably a reference resp. context error.  In general it's ofc possible to pass `page` object as argument.

Answer (score 0):

Before func3 add the keyword async. Later, write:

```
await func3(page)
```